# Perl - passing arguments to a subroutine as hash key-value pairs problem

Tags: perl, hash, subroutine

I have to pass two references as arguments to a subroutine (buildRanges) as hash key-value pairs as show below

Example:

```
@array = (“0A0”, “005”, “001”, “004”, “0BC”, “004”, “002”, “001”);
@ranges = ();
$numRanges = buildRanges(VALUES => \@array, REF_RANGES=>\@ranges);
```

My question is
1. is the syntax for the sub-routine call above is correct?
2. what are VALUES and REF_RANGES?

franckly speaking, i couldnt understand the sub-routine call, but i have been told to use that call only.

Thanks.

KK

Comment: You might also better understand the issues and the various options involved in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803808/how-do-i-pass-a-hash-to-a-function-in-perl/803871#803871

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Explanations**

Yes. This syntax is correct and idiomatic for Perl.  Let's dissect all parts of your function call --- most likely you already know parts of the explanation.

**Preparation: your input data**

```
@array = (“0A0”, “005”, “001”, “004”, “0BC”, “004”, “002”, “001”);
@ranges = ();
# \@array and \@ranges are now normal scalar references.
```

I hope you understand the concept of references to arrays.  If not, read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) or [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html).  Actually, this doesn't affect the calling syntax that you are asking about.  By the way, you might also have written:

```
$array_ref=[“0A0”, “005”, “001”, “004”, “0BC”, “004”, “002”, “001”];
$range_ref=[];

$numRanges = buildRanges(VALUES => $array_ref, REF_RANGES=> $range_ref);
```

**The function call**

In Perl, the arrow operator => is working just like a normal comma (with a small side-effect that we discuss in a moment).  The following calls are absolutely identical:

```
$numRanges = buildRanges(VALUES => $array_ref, REF_RANGES => $range_ref);
$numRanges = buildRanges("VALUES", $array_ref, "REF_RANGES", $range_ref);
```

So, you are simply calling the function buildRanges with four arguments: two constant strings and two array references.  You noticed that the word VALUES was changed to a constant string "VALUE"; the same applied to the word REF_RANGES. This is the special rule: before an arrow => and inside curly brackets {}, plain identifiers are silently converted to strings.  We see this again below.  But other expressions like $a => $b stay as they are, no silent conversions to strings happen here.

You may be asking why does Perl do this?  This is **syntactic sugar**: The => operator does nothing that you couldn't do easily without it.  But for experienced perl programmers the format  KEY => $value looks clearer than "KEY", $value.

**The function definition**

The definition of the function buildRanges may look like this (and we use this in our explanation):

```
sub buidRanges { my(%info)=@_; 
  my $values    = $info{VALUES};
  my $ref_ranges= $info{REF_RANGES};
  my $special_feature = $info{SPECIAL_FEATURE}; # explained below
  if($special_feature) { ... return special_result; }
  ... process $values and $ref_ranges ... return $numRanges.
}
```

With your input data, each of the following four lines have the same effect:

```
my(%info)=@_;                                          # the actual code
my(%info)=(VALUES => \@array, REF_RANGES=> \@ranges ); # what this does

my %info; $info{"VALUES"}=\@array; $info{"REF_RANGES"}=\@ranges; 
my %info; $info{ VALUES }=\@array; $info{ REF_RANGES }=\@ranges;
```

Basically, the input data is converted into a hash that allows access to each argument.  The constant strings in the function call become hash keys.

Pick one line that you understand and compare it to the other lines: They do the same thing. Look at [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more explanations.

Note that @_ is the array of input arguments, in our case

```
@_ = ( VALUES => \@array, REF_RANGES=> \@ranges); 
@_ = ("VALUES",  \@array,"REF_RANGES", \@ranges);  # without syntactic sugar
```

You may have noticed that $info{VALUES} is equivalent to $info{"VALUES"} -- again, this is syntactic sugar, as explained above.

Further down in our hypothetical implementation, we pull the input data out of the hash:

```
 my $values     = $info{VALUES};       # i.e:  my $value      = \@array;
 my $ref_ranges = $info{REF_RANGES};   # i.e:  my $ref_renges = \@ranges;
```

Now, our function implementation can work with the input data.

**Why do we do this not simpler? --- Named arguments**

So far, we could have achieved a similar effect much simpler:

```
$numRanges = buildRanges($array_ref, $range_ref);  # simpler function call

sub buidRanges { my($values, $ref_ranges)=@_; 
  ... process $values and $ref_ranges ... return $numRanges.
}
```

This is most likely the programming style that you already understand well.

So: Why make it some Perl programmers more complicated (and also much slower)?
The answer is: It's more flexible, and somewhat more self-documenting.

To make the point more clear, I added a SPECIAL_FEATURE to our function definition.  Now, the function can also be called like this:

```
$numRanges = buildRanges(VALUES => \@array, SPECIAL_FEATURE=> "infinite ranges");
```

The implemented function can tell that the SPECIAL_FEATURE is requested and that the REF_RANGES are not provided.

In some high-level functions, you have quite a number of extra features that are sometimes (but not always) useful, so it makes a lot of sense to let the caller decide which features to use and which not.  Here, the named arguments come in handy.

Of course, I can't tell you what special features are recognized by *your* 
buildRanges function --- you need to look at its implementation or ask the person that told you to use it.  It's also possible that, as a general convention, *all* high-level functions in some project use this calling style, even though *some* of them don't provide much special features.

Comment: Good explanation, especially since you didn't cop-out and bitch about not knowing what the OP's code does.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yaakov. I didnt give the full problem statement coz someone might give the entire code, which i want to do it myself. I will post code in a day for verification. Thanks again. :)